# Set auto-increment of primary ID manually or depending on another table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I think I will be asking a very confusing question so I hope I can make this very clear for you guys, so, thanks in advance, and I'm sorry if this is a bit long because I want to make sure that I am being clear enough.

I have two tables (in SQL 2005) which are kind of dependent to each other (let's name them TableA and TableB.) They have all the same columns, meaning, all TableA's columns are also TableB's columns, except that TableA has two more columns than TableB (it will be explained later why).

In the 'saving' process of my application (created using VB.Net), those records that has values for column1 and column2 gets inserted into TableA. But if there is no any input for column1 and column2, the record gets saved in Table2 (this is why TableA has two more columns than TableB: the records with column1 and column2 gets into TableA while those that don't have gets into TableB.)

Both tables have an identity primary key (auto-increment +1, starts at 1000), which we'll call KeyID_A for TableA and KeyID_B for TableB, and if you can already imagine the scenario, their key IDs have the same values (TableA has a row where the KeyID_A is '1000', and TableB also has a row (a different one) where KeyID_B is '1000').

In the application, the form (where the records being inserted in TableA/TableB are inputted) is auto-numbered (I set this using `SELECT nextID=MAX(KeyID_A)+1 FROM TableA`, yes, only from TableA, and that leads to my problem).

If I saved a record with values for column1 and column2, the record gets inserted in TableA, with KeyID_A's value as the key. But what if I don't have values for column1 and column2, and the record gets saved in TableB with KeyID_A's value as the key, how am I going to get the next ID (note: `SELECT nextID=MAX(KeyID_A)+1 FROM TableA`) if the supposed to be next ID for TableA is already used in TableB? I would want to get the next ID based on the existing records from both TableA and TableB, and not only based on TableA (because I thought, what if I have already used TableA's nextID for TableB (let's say '1001', and I want to save another record into TableB, but the auto-numbering that appears is still '1001' because it is based only from TableA's KeyID_A.

I am really confused on how to do this, if this is even possible. I hope I made my question clear enough.

Comment: Do you have multiple users that insert data in these two tables concurrently?

Comment: I'm sure that I only have one user.

Comment: Well, I suggest to add a third table (C) that stores only one record, the latest id used. When you insert in A or B select the next id from this table, save you data and increment the value of the only record present in C. By the way, if this is a scenario where you decide the ID then remove the IDENTITY from A and B

Comment: Oh...I see. I have never thought about creating a new table/view so that both tables have only one source of primary key. What I tried was to nest IF-ELSE statements to test if that key already exists in TableB or not, maybe that's why I'm going crazy. And then I'll find out that the solution is pretty simple. Thanks to all of you, your answers are very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should never do this the way you do.

Either you make it right which is:
solution 1:

```
TableA
Id : int PK (identity)
col1
col2
...

TableB
Id: int PK FK on TableA.Id
col8
col9
```

and create a view to make things simpler for you.

Solution 2:
Create table TableB with nullable col8 and col9
and a view called TableA if needed.

or the wrong way:

```
TableIdForAandB
Id : int PK identity

TableA
Id : int PK FK on TableIdForAandB.Id
col1
col2
...

TableB
Id : int PK FK on TableIdForAandB.Id
col1
col2
...
col8
col9
```

in which case you have to insert row to table TableIdForAandB and then insert row to table TableA or to TableB and set the Id to the new Id from TableIdForAandB.

Answer (score 1):

Think about using ONE sequencer for both tables or if you don't have one think about using always

```
nextID = MAX(MAX(KeyID_A), MAX(KeyID_B)) + 1
```

in addition your IDs will be unique (very much better :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you are duplicating your data in 2 tables. However your given scenario can be handled using **1 to 1 link**.

Your `TableB` will be your base table which has less columns, and `TableA` will be an extension table, but it will NOT have the columns which are already in `TableB`, it will only have the other 2 columns and a primary key.

In this way, you will always insert data in `TableB` first and if you have the data in other 2 columns then you will also insert a line in `TableA`, and at this point you will have the ID inserted in `TableB`, you will be using same ID.

Comment: I store them on separate tables because they will need to be retrieved separately sometime. :-)

Comment: If a separate retrieving is the only reason, why not using a view to handle user rights?